# MySQL Columns from Recordset

Tags: mysql

Maybe I am looking at this all wrong or something. I have this table, prices. When I new price is reported it goes into the table and has the type, price, stationid, and date. I can get the result but I want to have the stationid listed and the different fuel types and their prices in the columns.

Here is a sample table http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c04c/1

This is what I am going for, the latest price for each station for each row:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
stationid    |    regular    |     regDateAdded    |    midgrade    |     midDateAdded    |    premium    |    preDateAdded
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
52775        |      3.61     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |     3.71       | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |      3.81     |     0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Maybe I am over thinking this as well.

Comment: How do you determine the latest price?  In the Fiddle you provided, what should be the result for `stationid = 53011` since they have the same date?

Comment: When there is more dates, I would determine the lasted price as the last updated based on the `dateadded`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this can result in ties (if multiple stations share the same max dateadded), here is a common approach joining the table to itself using the `max` aggregate:

```
select p.stationid, p.price, p.fueltypeid, p.dateadded
from prices p
  join (select stationid, max(dateadded) maxdateadded
        from prices
        group by stationid) p2 on 
    p.stationid = p2.stationid and p.dateadded = p2.maxdateadded
```

- [Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c04c/4)

Comment: Please review my question again. I updated the expected result.

Comment: @BrandonWilson -- the query provided will return the station and corresponding record that was last entered by dateadded (using `max(dateadded)`).  Looking over your results, are you trying to `pivot` your results?

Comment: Actually, yes a pivot might be the answer.

Comment: @BrandonWilson -- check out this updated fiddle.  You can pivot results with `max` and `case`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f282e/1

Comment: when this is ran it pulling the `MAX` price not the `MAX` date and price. I've been trying to figure out how to get the date for each price but haven't been successful, would you be able to help?

Comment: @BrandonWilson -- just wrap the above query as a subquery and use `max` with `case` to `pivot` the results.  here you go: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f282e/3

Comment: did I do something wrong, I added a few more records and most of the results come up `null` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bbc3/3

Comment: My guess is this is what you're looking for -- the max date per station per type: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bbc3/4.  The other was returning the max date per station, and then using that to return the types that match.